# VLSM Calculator - Programming logic?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, network-programming, python-3.8

**I would like to realize a VLSM calculation function in Python3, in the same way as this site: *https://subnettingpractice.com/vlsm.html* but purely in command line (Python).**

Here is a preview of the code I've done so far:

```
import sys
from sys import argv
import os
from os import system
import ipaddress
from ipaddress import IPv4Address
from ipaddress import IPv4Network

def vlsm(x):

    if "/" in x:

        ipaddrCidrAndVLSM=x.split(" ")
        
        (ip,cidr)=ipaddrCidrAndVLSM[0].split("/")
        
        VLSMValues=ipaddrCidrAndVLSM[1:]
        SubnetNumbers=VLSMValues[0]
        HostsValues=VLSMValues[1:]

        ipaddr=ipaddress.ip_network(ipaddrCidrAndVLSM[0], strict=False)

        if (int(SubnetNumbers)!=len(HostsValues)):
            print("\033[0;31mThe number of subnets entered does not match the number of hosts.\033[00m")
            exit(1)

    else:
        print("\033[0;31mAn unexpected error was caused.\033[00m")
        exit(1)

    mask=ipaddr.netmask
    size=ipaddr.num_addresses-2
    firstHost=ipaddr[1]
    lastHost=ipaddr[size]
    br=ipaddr.broadcast_address
    is_private=ipaddr.is_private
    is_global=ipaddr.is_global

    subnets=[]
    for subnet in ipaddr.subnets(prefixlen_diff=0):
        subnets.append(subnet)

    sn=len(subnets)

    return ipaddr,mask,size,firstHost,lastHost,br,sn,subnets,is_private,is_global

print(vlsm("192.168.0.1/24 4 100 50 20 10"))
```

**The user can choose the number of sites (subnet), then the number of hosts per subnet:**

```
print(vlsm("192.168.0.1/24 4 100 50 20 10"))
```

**4 -> Subnet number, 100 -> Site (subnet), 50-> Site (subnet), 20-> Site (subnet), 10-> Site (subnet)**

**Currently I am completely lost, I wonder how I could proceed to continue my program... I'm stressed and lost because I'm not used to getting stuck on problems but right now I'm just plain lost.**

**I found some Github projects in graphical version but being a beginner in Python, I really don't get by. I hope that the community, that a more experienced person can help me, and even explain me his answer.**

**I thank you in advance. Sorry if my code is not very optimized again I am a beginner in Python.**

Comment: You should first completely understand how to do IPv4 math. [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) first explains the math, then it goes into detail about subnetting. If you want to do more than the regular IP library, learn how to write the code from the bottom up using IPv4 math.

Comment: I'm already interested in it but I have a hard time representing the way/logic I have to do my code for the realization of a VLSM calculation function.

Comment: Convert the text representation to an integer, then you can use integer math (`AND` , `OR`, `SHIFT`, etc.) to do the calculations before turning it back into a text representation. The necessary algorithms are explained in the answer I linked, and you can implement them in most programming languages.